# Check if the point is within the Google Maps polygon in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I have some areas that are divided into polygons on my google maps, I would like some way to identify if a certain point is inside the polygon. I just tried the Ray Casting algorithm that identifies the point in the polygon, but the result was not good. It does not work with very irregular polygons, in my tests the implementation is not viable.

I'll leave here what I tried to do.

Ray Casting Function:

```
  bool rayCastIntersect(LatLng tap, LatLng vertA, LatLng vertB) {
    double aY = vertA.latitude;
    double bY = vertB.latitude;
    double aX = vertA.longitude;
    double bX = vertB.longitude;
    double pY = tap.latitude;
    double pX = tap.longitude;

    if ((aY > pY && bY > pY) || (aY < pY && bY < pY) || (aX < pX && bX < pX)) {
      return false; // a and b can't both be above or below pt.y, and a or
      // b must be east of pt.x
    }
```

Function to check if the marker is inside the polygon, continuation of Ray Casting:

```
 bool _checkIfValidMarker(LatLng tap, List<LatLng> vertices) {
    int intersectCount = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < vertices.length - 1; j++) {
      if (rayCastIntersect(tap, vertices[j], vertices[j + 1])) {
        intersectCount++;
      }
    }

    return ((intersectCount % 2) == 1); // odd = inside, even = outside;
  }
```

Declaration of test areas:

```
 List<LatLng> _areaRed = [
    LatLng(-20.54564560298607, -48.93099261363096),
    LatLng(-20.47020914370705, -47.585960450443444),
    LatLng(-20.888624642495724, -47.564486265123804),
    LatLng(-21.275431646124073, -47.44904100868184),
    LatLng(-21.53038557354785, -48.50412611872714)
  ];
  List<LatLng> _areaBlue = [
    LatLng(-20.583742560626508, -47.36628976946108),
    LatLng(-19.732037376448474, -47.11388584796422),
    LatLng(-20.091216049597158, -46.00876597546445),
    LatLng(-20.70503248593602, -46.48287604422207),
    LatLng(-21.297307144955976, -47.24008780871265)
  ];
  List<LatLng> _areaGreen = [
    LatLng(-20.588467827088945, -48.26017166238112),
    LatLng(-18.32058633744915, -50.27657970099416),
    LatLng(-17.474497720584548, -48.19666274777912),
    LatLng(-17.988676302476964, -46.25964085241858),
    LatLng(-18.877360628508573, -46.9899933703414)
  ];
```

Calling the function to check the points within a certain area. _currentLocation.latitude refers to the location taken by the GPS, but I also tested it with fixed coordinates.

```
   insideArea = _checkIfValidMarker(LatLng(_currentLocation.latitude, _currentLocation.longitude),            
   _areaGreen);
```

Comment: You can try using [google_map_polyutil](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_polyutil) package. It has a method 'containsLocation' that computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon

Comment: I considered this possibility, but the package is very outdated in consideration with my other package packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve using [maps_toolkit](https://pub.dev/packages/maps_toolkit) using PolygonUtil.containsLocation - computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.
It conflicted with my Google Maps package, so I created an isolated class just to check and send the response to my main screen.
Sorry for my English..

Comment: Thanks for the response. would you please share the Isolated Class